# How do i forward all urls to another url

Tags: .htaccess

How do I forward all URLs to another URL

So all

http://www.example.com

will go to

https://new.example.com

**and**

http://www.example.com/im/a/url

will forward to

https://new.example.com/im/a/url

**and finally**

one specific url **will not** forward:

http://www.example.com/im/ANOTHER/url

will **stay** going to

http://www.example.com/im/ANOTHER/url

in my htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

In example.com / :

```
RewriteEngine On 
Redirect permanent / http://new.example.com/
```

Comment: but **one specific URL should not forward** [http://www.example.com/im/ANOTHER/url](http://www.example.com/im/ANOTHER/url)...

Comment: If you redirect / to example/ -> /index go to example/index... So I think it works.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988: I think you want to exclude `/im/ANOTHER/url` from this redirect, right?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^im/ANOTHER/url http://new.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,NC,R=301,L]
```